# Corrupt data after apply CUDA kernel

Tags: c, cuda

I was playing with a kernel that maps an array with floats with a function. I don't know why but each time I run the program, the old results are added to the new results (it sounds to me like cudaFree wasn't setting free memory, but the return of the function is 0).

For example, the original number 0.758846 after the 1st kernel execution was -0.123258, but after some new executions, the result is -9.996812

This is the kernel and the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define PI 3.1415926

/* f(x) = sum from i = 1 to m sin(2 * PI * i * x) */
__global__ void mapping(float *data_d, int sample_size, int m) {
    int i;
    int tid = blockIdx.x;
    float sum;
    if(tid < sample_size) {
        for(i = 1; i < m + 1; i++)
            sum += sin(2 * PI * i * data_d[tid]);
        data_d[tid] = sum;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int sample_size;
    float *data_h, *data_d;
    float num;
    FILE *fp;

    /* Get data fom file */
    if((fp = fopen("data.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &sample_size);

        data_h = (float*)malloc(sample_size * sizeof(float));

        for(i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%f", &num) != EOF; i++)
            data_h[i] = num;

        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        perror("data.txt");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sample_size; i++)
        printf("%f\n", data_h[i]);

    /* Allocate memory on device */
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data_d, sample_size * sizeof(int));
    /* Copy data from host to device */
    cudaMemcpy(data_d, data_h, sample_size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /* kernel */
    mapping <<< sample_size, 1 >>> (data_d, sample_size, 3);

    cudaMemcpy(data_h, data_d, sample_size * sizeof(int),
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("--------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < sample_size; i++)
        printf("%f\n", data_h[i]);

    /* Free memory used */
    cudaFree(data_d);
    free(data_h);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if my code is wrong, or is something beyond. I do preffer first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing `sum` before you start adding to it in the kernel.

Comment: I will retire soon... by the way, why does this happens? it is just a coincidence that the value stored execution after execution is the same result?

Comment: The result you described seems like the logical consequence of not initializing the memory if you consider it to be fairly likely that `sum` gets assigned to the same address in GPU memory each time you run the program.

Comment: Interesting! I haven't notice that. Thanks for your help